# Better way to say "ensure that the job is done right"?

Tags: phrases, alternatives

I'm copy editing a contract proposal and the last part of final paragraph of the executive summary says "x y and z ... ensure that job is done right." This is a bit bland. Any suggestions on how to elevate this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

"x y and z...I want to guarantee that the job is done right."